# Display: fullscreen doesn't work on manifest json

Tags: javascript, mobile-website, progressive-web-apps, manifest.json

I want my progressive web app to appear fullscreen without the chrome address/toolbar shown up on top when I add it to homescreen. Therefor I added display:fullscreen on manifest.json but it doesn't work. Here is my manifest.json code:

```
{
  "name": "Cardiofit",
  "short_name": "Cardiofit",
  "description": "Modern app for your health",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "images/cardio192.png",
      "sizes": "192x192",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "images/cardio512.png",
      "sizes": "512x512",
      "type": "image/png"
    }
  ],
  "display": "fullscreen",
  "start_url": "/",
  "orientation": "portrait"
}
```

I connected my smartphone with usb cable to my computer and opened chrome on my computer. Then navigated to "remote devices" in chrome inspector so I could surf to localhost on my android to see how the app would look like when it's added to homescreen. But I can stil see the browser address-toolbar on top of it even after declaring "display: fullscreen" on manifest.json.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

When you add an app to home screen with "Add to Home screen" option, Chrome will add the icon to the home screen, but behind the scene, it might have done one of two different things.

1) If the website you are trying to add meets all [PWA criteria](https://developers.google.com/web/progressive-web-apps/checklist), Chrome will use WebAPK component to build an .APK file, sign it and install in the device. To validate all PWA criteria for yourself, use Chrome dev tools -> Audit -> Perform audit -> progressive web app.

2) If the site is not a qualified PWA, it will still add an icon, which will open a browser when you click on it with address bar. This seems to be happening in your case. I understand you have manifest.json file. Good chances its not served properly(due to your packaging and build process may be). To verify it, use Chrome developer tools -> Application -> Manifest to know if your manifest is reaching the browser.

I would recommend you to use HTTPS and Service workers along with manifest.json, at a minimum along with other things [explained here](https://developers.google.com/web/progressive-web-apps/checklist) as needed to make it a basic minimum PWA.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I had the same problem as described above. After running the audit, I saw that I needed an automatic redirect to the HTTPS protocol. Once I set that up in the htaccess, my PWA opened fullscreen.